# DatePicker in custom visual is showing wrong dates

Tags: powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to add a Date Picker component in Format Pane, but it shows a wrong date.
Here's my implementation:

Capabilities.json file:

```
..."properties": {
        "Date1": {
          "displayName": "Start date",
          "description": "Select start date",
          "type": {
            "text": true
          }
        },...
```

Setting.ts class:

```
export class DateFields {
  public Date1: Date = null;
  public Date2: Date = null;
 }
```

Formatting pane model (powerbi.visuals.FormattingGroup.slices):

```
{
                    displayName: "Date 1",
                    uid: `datacard_holidays_holiday${i}_startDate`,
                    control: {
                        type: FormattingComponent.DatePicker,
                        properties: {
                            placeholder: "Start Date",
                            descriptor: {
                                objectName: "holidays",
                                propertyName: `startDate${i}`,
                            },
                            value: settings.holidays[`startDate${i}`],
                        },
                    },
                },
```

And I can see the Date Picker in Format Pane model, but whenever I'm selecting any dates, it shows some other date.

GIF:

[image]

This is the format of the selected date (when I debug): `Mon Jan 01 2024 17:12:11 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`.

I'm getting the correct date in my visual or when I try to debug. Do I need to use some other "type" in Capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by using ``` new Date(settings.holidays[``startDate${i}``]) ``` in Formatting pane model.

Updated formatting pane model:

```
{
                    displayName: "Date 1",
                    uid: `datacard_holidays_holiday${i}_startDate`,
                    control: {
                        type: FormattingComponent.DatePicker,
                        properties: {
                            placeholder: "Start Date",
                            descriptor: {
                                objectName: "holidays",
                                propertyName: `startDate${i}`,
                            },
                            value: new Date(settings.holidays[`startDate${i}`]),
                        },
                    },
                },
```